# Simple golang server script not working as exe

Tags: go, build

I found a golang script to run a localhost server. This is it,

server.go

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {

    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("G:/build")))

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
    
}
```

It works fine serving "G:/build" folder, but I want to build it as an exe file. I read that I have to use `os.Args[1]` to get the first command line argument, so I added it like this -

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {

    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("os.Args[1]")))

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
    
}
```

When I build the exe it builds fine with no errors. If I run the exe with the only argument as "g:/build" I get no errors and no webpage on my browser at localhost:8080. Sort of stuck now. Anything obviously wrong? I'm on Windows (had to use front slashes in the folder path as shown). I also tried importing "os" but it would not even build (said I'm not using it), which seems strange since I'm using "os.Args[1]" in the code??

Comment: `http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(os.Args[1])))`